# How do i change the font size of a paragraph tag inside a div tag?

Tags: html, css

I just started a new project and I have run into a problem. My problem is that I cannot increase the font size of a paragraph tag that is inside a div tag. I also have a problem getting  my paragraph tag centered in the center of the div.

```css
div {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
.gases {
  background-color: limegreen;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>The Periodic Table</title>
  <style>
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="periodOne groupOne gases" id="hydrogen">
    <p>H</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: How did you try increasing the font size? As for centering, consider using flex layout (search for flexbox) if you are targeting modern browsers; but in your case it seems you might not even need to center, you could use sizes in `em` or `rem` terms.

Comment: @owen I have tried to use fomt-size in both my style tag and as an inline style tag

Comment: You're talking about what you did but you aren't showing what you did. That's not going to work here.

Answer (score 4):

You can just increase the **`font-size`** of the paragraph and add a **`line-height`** equal to the height of the **`div`** to center it vertically.

**Code:**

```css
/* ----- CSS ----- */
div {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
.gases {
  background-color: limegreen;
}
#paragraph {
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!----- HTML ----->
<div class="periodOne groupOne gases" id="hydrogen">
  <p id="paragraph">H</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm glad I could help @Jake_the_camper.

Answer (score 1):

You can add class to p tag and then give font-size,

```
.paragraph {
   font-size: 15px;
}
```

You can vertically center the text inside div by,

```
.gases {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

You can also horizontally center content by adding,

```
justify-content: center;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can style the tags directly, however, be aware this is a global change.

```
   div p {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 1.3em;
        width: 100%;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem 1:-
I cannot increase the font size of a paragraph tag that is inside a div tag

Solution 1
->Make id for the paragraph tag and apply font-size on it.

Solution 2
-> you can directly change it size by just writing

```
p{
   font-size:32px;
 }
```

but best approach will be using of id so this paragraph can be identified uniquely.

Problem 2:-
 I also have a problem getting my paragraph tag centered in the center of the div

```
div {
   height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    text-align: center;
 }
```

You have write this code.In this code you are giving text-align center to div.
So it will send any thing to center which will be inside this div(not only this div every div on this page )

Solution 1
->you can remove this css property

Solution 2 
-> you can also write this to get it back where it was

```
  p{
       text-align:left;
    }
```

Whole solution is

```
    <!--HTML-->
    <div class="periodOne groupOne gases" id="hydrogen">
       <p id="increaseFont">That's how you can incrrease font man</p>
    </div>



//css 
div {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    text-align: center;
 }
.gases {
    background-color: limegreen;
 }
 #increaseFont{
     font-size:23px;
  }
  p{
      text-align:left;
   }
```

Answer (score -1):

another way.... instead of adding another id tag, you can use this..

```
hydrogen>p{
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 50px;
}
```

Both ways work equally, but this keeps your HTML cleaner